# Using Amazon Trust Services certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-systems-manager

I want to set up systems manager on my own on-premises servers. According to the AWS SSM document, I have to install and enable a certificate from Amazon Trust Services using AWS Certificate Manager. I think this document is very old and it shows many incorrect instruction. I can't find anything related to the Amazon Trust Services there and nor does the instruction to use these certificates. Can anyone provide me with any help?

Comment: Please provide a link to the document in question.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html  This is the document of aws certificate manager.

Comment: Are you referring to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/hybrid-tls-certificate.html from SSM context?